# Using basic auth with gstreamer souphttpsrc

Tags: c, gstreamer, basic-authentication

We are using the gstreamer souphttpsrc in a gstreamer pipeline to access and forward at http stream. To access the httpstream we have to use BasicAuth. We know how to format the basic auth header but we have trouble passing the header via the souphttpsrc extra-headers parameter as a GstStructure.

Currently we are using the command below

```
gst-launch-1.0 spuphttsrc location="http://streamsource" extra-headers="Authorization: Basic base64hash" ! ...
```

The rest of the pipeline has been left out as it has been tested previously and is working.

The error we receive: `canot set property extra-headers`

The source code for gstreamer can be found here: https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good

The GstStructure docs can be found here: http://web.mit.edu/ghudson/dev/nokrb/third/gstreamer/docs/gst/html/gstreamer-GstStructure.html

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Can't you just set your auth in the uri in the form of `http://username:password@streamsoruce` and you are done?

Comment: We actually managed to fix this. I will post an answer myself soon. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having faced this issue myself for several days I finally landed at exactly the point at which I started. My mistake was that I did not properly escape whitespace.

### Error

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location="http://streamsource" extra-headers="test,Authorization=Bearer\ eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c"

WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not set property "extra-headers" in element "souphttpsrc0"
```

Notice I did add `\` to escape the whitespace in `Bearer <Token>`, but its not enough.

### Solution

#### gst-launch-1.0

The solution is to wrap the `value` part of `key=value` in `\"<value>\"` as shown below to use the `\`:

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location="http://streamsource" extra-headers="test,Authorization=(string)\"Bearer\ eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c\""
```

Hint: If you want to be explicit you can add its type as well infront of `value` like `(string)\"value\"`.

#### gstreamer-java/gst1-java-core

What prompted my problem initially was that I was not able to setup set `extra-headers` in the java bindings, figured I might as well add it here.

In Java:

```java
String token = "mytoken";
Element httpSrc = ElementFactory.make("souphttpsrc", "test_src");
httpSrc.setAsString("extra-headers", "test, Authorization=Bearer $authToken");
```

or in Kotlin:

```kotlin
val token: String = "mytoken"
val httpSrc: Element = ElementFactory.make("souphttpsrc", "test_src")
httpSrc.setAsString("extra-headers", "test, Authorization=Bearer $authToken")
```

Further reading that helped me:

- [gststructure tests](https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer/blob/master/tests/check/gst/gststructure.c#L234)
- [gstructure serialization format](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gststructure.html?gi-language=c)