# Gstreamer C code for adding extra-header tokens in souphttpsrc

Tags: c, http-headers, gstreamer

I am accessing a file on an https server that requires an authorization token. From Windows cmd line, the following call discussed in the post [Using basic auth with gstreamer souphttpsrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56036937/using-basic-auth-with-gstreamer-souphttpsrc) works without any issues:

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location="https://hls.rtst.co.za/video/france24/ovmaster.m3u8" extra-headers='test,Authorization=(string)\"Bearer\ eyJhbGci...token...psMshNg\"' ! filesink location="fetched/ovmaster.m3u8"
```

However, when I tried to implement it in C code it fails. My code fragment is:

```
  // Set the source location parameter on the souphttpsrc element
  GstElement* urisrc  = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(data->pipeline), "httphlssrc");
  g_object_set(urisrc, "location", from.c_str(), NULL);

  // Add to token to GET header
  // extra-headers='test,Authorization=(string)"Bearer\ eyJh....token.....SKrbJJnHA"'
  string src = data->uriSrcName;
  if (!data->token.empty())
  {
    gchar* authChar = "test,Authorization=(string)\"Bearer\ eyJhbG...token...JpsMshNg\"";
    GstStructure* extraHeaders = gst_structure_new("extra-headers", "authorization", G_TYPE_STRING, authChar, NULL);

    g_object_set(urisrc, "extra-headers", extraHeaders, NULL);

    gst_structure_free(extraHeaders);
  }//end if token...

  g_object_unref(urisrc);
```

The error is printed as:

```
Error received from element httphlssrc: Unauthorized../ext/soup/gstsouphttpsrc.c(1436): gst_soup_http_src_parse_status (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSoupHTTPSrc:httphlssrc:
Unauthorized (401), URL: https://hls.rtst.co.za/video/france24/ovmaster.m3u8, Redirect to: (NULL)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of using a GstStructure appears to be lacking and a gst_structure_from_string() is the correct function to use. The code segment that worked is as follows:

```
  // Add to token to GET header
  // extra-headers='test,Authorization=(string)"Bearer\ eyJh.........SKrbJJnHA"'
  string src = data->uriSrcName;
  if (!data->token.empty())
  {
    string authStr = "token, Authorization=(string)\"Bearer\\ " + data->token + "\"";
    GstStructure* extraHeaders = gst_structure_from_string((const gchar*)(authStr.c_str()), NULL);
    if (extraHeaders != NULL)
    {
      g_object_set(urisrc, "extra-headers", extraHeaders, NULL);
      gst_structure_free(extraHeaders);
    }//end if extraHeaders...
  }//end if token...
```